# PyBrain: MemoryError: while loading training dataset

Tags: neural-network, pybrain

I am trying to train a feedforward neural network, for binary classification. My Dataset is 6.2M with 1.5M dimension. I am using PyBrain. I am unable to load even a single datapoint. I am getting MemoryError. [image: MemoryError]

My Code snippet is:

```
Train_ds = SupervisedDataSet(FV_length, 1) #FV_length is a computed value. 150000
feature_vector = numpy.zeros((FV_length),dtype=numpy.int)
#activate feature values
for index in nonzero_index_list:
        feature_vector[index] = 1

Train_ds.addSample(feature_vector,class_label) # both the arguments are tuples
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your computer just does not have the memory to add your feature and class label arrays to the supervised data set Train_ds.

If there is no way for you to allocate more memory to your system it might be a good idea to random sample from your data set and train on the smaller sample.

This should still give accurate results assuming the sample is large enough to be representative.